# JAVA: Moving an Object in a Borderpane when button is pressed

Tags: java, object, javafx, event-handling

I am working on a homework assignment where I need to create a circle in a pane and move it using buttons at the bottom of the screen. I am able to get the circle and buttons to appear in the pane, but when I press a button, the circle does not move.

My main method is as follows:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MoveBall extends Application {  
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Circle ball = new Circle(10);
    Button btUp = new Button("Up");
    Button btDown = new Button("Down");
    Button btLeft = new Button("Left");
    Button btRight = new Button("Right");
    
    
    HBox pane = new HBox();
    BorderPane bPane = new BorderPane();
    
    
    
    ball.setFill(Color.RED);
    ball.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    pane.setSpacing(10);
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    pane.getChildren().addAll(btUp, btDown, btLeft, btRight);
    bPane.setCenter(ball);
    bPane.setBottom(pane);
    
    btUp.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> BallControl.moveUp(ball));
    btDown.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> BallControl.moveDown(ball));
    btLeft.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> BallControl.moveLeft(ball));
    btRight.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> BallControl.moveRight(ball));
    
    
  
  Scene scene = new Scene(bPane, 400, 400);
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  primaryStage.setTitle("Move the Ball");
  primaryStage.show();
  }
  
  public static void main (String[] args)  
  {  
      launch(args);  
  }  
  
  
}
```

And the method to actually move the circle is here:

```
class BallControl{
  public static void moveUp(Circle circle){
    if(circle.getCenterY() - circle.getRadius() - 10 < 0) return;
      circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY() - 10);
  }
      
  public static void moveDown(Circle circle){
    if(circle.getCenterY() + circle.getRadius() + 10 > 400) return;
    circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY() + 10);
  }
          
  public static void moveLeft(Circle circle){
    if(circle.getCenterX() - circle.getRadius() - 10 < 0) return;
    circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() - 10);
  }
              
    public static void moveRight(Circle circle){
      if(circle.getCenterX() + circle.getRadius() + 10 > 400) return;
      circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() + 10);
    }
}
```

The intent with the BallControl method is to check if moving the circle would extend it past the boundaries of the window and if it does not, to move it. But the circle never moves when the button is pressed.

Comment: Use `Pane` not `BorderPane`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635541/circle-movement-upon-rectangle-collision/47638860#47638860

Comment: Or use both: put the circle in a pane, and the pane in the center of the border pane.

Answer (score 3):

A `BorderPane` is a type of "layout pane", which means it will lay its child nodes out according to its own algorithm. In particular, a `BorderPane` will expand the node in the `center` region to fill the entire region, if that node is resizable, and within the constraints specified by its min, max, and pref size, and then center it within that region. A `Circle` is not resizable, so it merely gets centered in the region.

Modifying the circle's `centerX` and `centerY` coordinates won't help here: the layout bounds of the circle will be a rectangle approximately 20x20 pixels (because the radius is 10, so that is the smallest rectangle containing the circle; "approximately" here is because some additional space may be needed for the stroke). That rectangle will have a coordinate system starting at center-radius and extending to center+radius, but then that will be centered in the center region by the border pane's layout policy. Effectively, the coordinates of the circle's center change but those are only within the coordinate system of the circle itself, not in the coordinate system of the border pane.

One solution is to wrap the circle in a regular `Pane`, which performs no layout, and place the `Pane` in the center of the `BorderPane`. The `Pane` is resizable, so the `BorderPane` will resize it to the full size of the center region. The `Pane` will not lay out the circle, so it remains at its coordinates defined by `centerX` and `centerY` without any additional layout. (Effectively, you make the coordinate system of the circle the same as the coordinate system of the pane.) This is the solution I use in the code below.

Another solution is to manipulate the `translateX` and `translateY` properties of the circle. Those transforms are applied *after* layout. However, with this solution it becomes more complicated to prevent the circle escaping the boundaries of its container. (I have not shown this solution in the code below.)

See the [layout documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html) for more details.

Here is the modification to make this work. Note I also modified how the boundaries are computed, so it still works if the window is resized.

```
package org.jamesd.examples.movingball;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MoveBall extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Circle ball = new Circle(200, 200, 10);
        Button btUp = new Button("Up");
        Button btDown = new Button("Down");
        Button btLeft = new Button("Left");
        Button btRight = new Button("Right");


        HBox controls = new HBox();
        BorderPane bPane = new BorderPane();



        ball.setFill(Color.RED);
        ball.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        controls.setSpacing(10);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        controls.getChildren().addAll(btUp, btDown, btLeft, btRight);

        Pane ballPane = new Pane(ball);
        bPane.setCenter(ballPane);
        bPane.setBottom(controls);

        btUp.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> moveUp(ball));
        btDown.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> moveDown(ball));
        btLeft.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> moveLeft(ball));
        btRight.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> moveRight(ball));



        Scene scene = new Scene(bPane, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Move the Ball");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void moveUp(Circle circle){
        if(circle.getCenterY() - circle.getRadius() - 10 < 0) return;
        circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY() - 10);
    }

    public void moveDown(Circle circle){
        if(circle.getCenterY() + circle.getRadius() + 10 > circle.getParent().getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()) return;
        circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY() + 10);
    }

    public void moveLeft(Circle circle){
        System.out.println(circle.getBoundsInLocal());
        if(circle.getCenterX() - circle.getRadius() - 10 < 0) return;
        circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() - 10);
    }

    public void moveRight(Circle circle){
        if(circle.getCenterX() + circle.getRadius() + 10 > circle.getParent().getBoundsInLocal().getWidth()) return;
        circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() + 10);
    }
}
```